# Disallow iframes from displaying page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can I disable people from using my page in an iframe. Is it possible using only HTML or must I use JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: you can by using a [Framekiller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller), but this site is to help you after you have problems in your attempts to write a framekiller or integrating an existing one, providing specific errors/warnings etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to approach this problem, which are explained in detail in the [Busting Frame Busting paper](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/framebusting/framebust.pdf) which I highly recommend you read if you have a chance to.

The first two options are using HTTP Headers, which don't use any HTML, JavaScript/jQuery, but do require configuration on your web server.

1. Use the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header.

   - `X-FRAME-OPTIONS: deny` - no rendering within a frame
   - `X-FRAME-OPTIONS: sameorigin` - no rendering if origin mismatch
2. The `Content-Security-Policy` header allows you to use the `frame-ancestors` directive
   to specify which origins are allowed to embed the page into a frame or an iframe. The downstide to this is it does not provide a way to enforce side wide policy.

   - Example of Twitter's CSP `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors *.twitter.com;`
   - Here's the browser compatibility - http://caniuse.com/contentsecuritypolicy

**EDIT**: `frame-ancestors` is actually part of [Content Security Policy Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/) for which the [compatibility can be seen here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2)

The suggested method is using the following snippet of code at the top of your page. It will hide your page's content if it is iframed and will reveal the content otherwise.

```
<style> html {display:none;} </style>
<script>
   if (self == top) {
       document.documentElement.style.display = 'block'; 
   } 
   else {
       top.location = self.location; 
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the break out of iframe script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (top.location != self.location) {
            top.location = self.location.href;
        }
</script>
```